# JavaScript else if statement issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Using Javascript for a project and I'm unable to get my else if statement to work or display the blocks I've designated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("form").submit(function(event){

var like = parseInt($("input:radio[name=like]:checked").val());
var building = parseInt($("#building").val());
var language = parseInt($("#language").val());
var clients = parseInt($("#clients").val());
var study = parseInt($("input:radio[name=study]:checked").val());
var successrate = (like + building + language + clients + study);
if(successrate >5 || <10) {
  $("#javaOut").show();
}else if (successrate >10 || successrate <=15) { then
  $("#phpOut").show();
}else {
  $("#designout").show();
  }
event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: You've got `{` before `then` in the first `else if`

Comment: `if(successrate >5 || <10)` invalid syntax.

Comment: `successrate >10 || successrate <=15` this doesn't make sense.. gues it should be `&&`

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the logic you have typo in below line `if(successrate >5 || <10) {`,it should be `if(successrate >5 || successrate <10) {`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(event){    
        var like = parseInt($("input:radio[name=like]:checked").val());
        var building = parseInt($("#building").val());
        var language = parseInt($("#language").val());
        var clients = parseInt($("#clients").val());
        var study = parseInt($("input:radio[name=study]:checked").val());
        var successrate = (like + building + language + clients + study);
        if(successrate >5 && successrate <10) { // was successrate >5 ||<10 => syntax error + always true condition
          $("#javaOut").show();
        }else if (successrate >10 && successrate <=15) { //was successrate >10 && successrate <=15 { then => syntax error + always true condition
          $("#phpOut").show();
        }else {
          $("#designout").show();
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You've some syntax errors and some mistakes in condition

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(event){    
        var like = parseInt($("input:radio[name=like]:checked").val());
        var building = parseInt($("#building").val());
        var language = parseInt($("#language").val());
        var clients = parseInt($("#clients").val());
        var study = parseInt($("input:radio[name=study]:checked").val());
        var successrate = (like + building + language + clients + study);
        if(successrate >5 && successrate <=10) { // was successrate >5 ||<10 => syntax error + always true condition
          $("#javaOut").show();
        }else if (successrate >10 && successrate <=15) { //was successrate >10 && successrate <=15 { then => syntax error + always true condition
          $("#phpOut").show();
        }else {
          $("#designout").show();
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: It's giving me: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < now

Comment: I changed it to the most recent edit and now for some reason it is only showing the else designated block?